# Automorphisms of rationally connected varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, automorphism-groups, fixed-point-theorems

Let $X$ be a smooth, rationally connected variety over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Denote by $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ the space of automorphisms of $X$ and for a given $\phi \in \mathrm{Aut}(X)$, denote by $\mathrm{Fix}(\phi)$ the fixed points of the automorphism $\phi$. I wanted to ask, if there is any known condition under which the intersection $F$ of all $\mathrm{Fix}(\phi)$ as $\phi$ ranges over all elements of $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ is the emptyset?

Comment: The identity component $G$ of the group scheme $\text{Aut}(X)$ is  linear. If every $G$-orbit has stabilizer group equal to a proper subgroup, then there is no point fixed by all of $\text{Aut}(X)$.  The dimension of the stabilizer group is the nullity of the fiber of the map $\mathfrak{g}\otimes \mathcal{O}_X \to T_X.$  There are plenty of other examples, e.g., an action of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with nontrivial "elementary obstruction" has empty fixed locus, cf. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284559/extending-commuting-automorphisms-of-a-field/284567#284567